# Google Maps API - not loading in Flex. Getting gray screen with map controls. 404 error & CrossDomain?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps, flex3

I'm having an issue with my Google Maps API, which I'm using withing a Flex application.

Periodically, I have to refresh it 5 or 6 times to get the map to display properly. Otherwise, I get one marker in the upper left corner and the map is greyed out. I don't even get an error message so I'm not sure what to trouble shoot.

I suspect it may have something to do with it triggering the onMapReady(event) as the map is being generated, but I don't know how to set up some type of timed listener in Flex. (I have Googled this but have only found instances in JavaScript or Jquery to do so.)

Can someone give me a tip on how to check for the maps being in an idle state using ActionScript/Flex? I think if I can get that part, I can remove the mapevent_mapready="onMapReady(event)" and just make the onMapReady(event) function run when the map is idle...or something like that. I've seen it for JavaScript but of course that won't directly work in AS and I don't know enough of either to make a proper translation.

Here's my code:

```
    public function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void {

var dojoGeo:Array = geoSchoolInfoAry; 

var md:MarkerData = new MarkerData(dojoGeo[0],dojoGeo[1]);

var latlng:LatLng = new LatLng(md.lat,md.lng); 


var markerOptions:MarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

markerOptions.icon = new dojoIcon(); 

var dojoMarker:Marker = new Marker(latlng,markerOptions);

map.addOverlay(dojoMarker);


var markerOptions2:MarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

markerOptions2.icon = new studentIcon(); 

var studentMarker:Marker = new Marker(latlng,markerOptions2);

map.addOverlay(studentMarker); 


map.setCenter(new LatLng(dojoGeo[0],dojoGeo[1]), 11, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);

map.addControl(new ZoomControl());

map.addControl(new MapTypeControl());

map.addControl(new ScaleControl()); 


addSchoolMarker(md,dojoMarker); 

addStudentsToMap(); 

}
```

And

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
    <maps:Map xmlns:maps="com.google.maps.*" id="map" key="map key here"  mapevent_mapready="onMapReady(event)" width="90%" height="90%"   sensor="false" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE: Using Firebug Developer tools, I discovered 2 errors. A CrossDomain.xml - Aborted and 404 Not Found error. Not exactly sure how to proceed with this since I don't know if these are just symptoms of whatever is causing the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have to thank my co-worker for finding a solution.

The problem was a timing issue, with the API being called at the same time as the functions were running with the data to populate the map. So he suggested that the mapOnReady event shouldn't run until the other 2 functions were completed.

Hope it can help someone who runs into a similar issue.

Here's the code:

```
    public function getGeoInfo_Handler(results):void
{
 try
 {

  geoSchoolInfoAry = (results.getSchoolInfo.split(","));

  geoInfoAC = new ArrayCollection(results.getInfo.split(";"));
  remoteCallComplete=true;
  loadMap();
 }
 catch (error:Error)
 {
  FlexException.errorHandler(error, "StudentPopMapModuleCode:getGeoInfoSchool_Handler");
 }
}
public function onMapReady(event:MapEvent = null):void
{
 mapReady=true;
 loadMap();
}

private function loadMap():void
{
 if(mapReady && remoteCallComplete)
 {
  var dojoGeo:Array = geoSchoolInfoAry;
  var md:MarkerData = new MarkerData(dojoGeo[0], dojoGeo[1]);
  var latlng:LatLng = new LatLng(md.lat, md.lng);

  map.setCenter(new LatLng(dojoGeo[0], dojoGeo[1]), 11, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
  map.addControl(new ZoomControl());
  map.addControl(new MapTypeControl());
  map.addControl(new ScaleControl());

  var markerOptions:MarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
  markerOptions.icon = new dojoIcon();
  var dojoMarker:Marker = new Marker(latlng, markerOptions);
  map.addOverlay(dojoMarker);

  var markerOptions2:MarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
  markerOptions2.icon = new studentIcon();
  var studentMarker:Marker = new Marker(latlng, markerOptions2);
  map.addOverlay(studentMarker);

  addSchoolMarker(md, dojoMarker);
  addStudentsToMap();
 }
}
```